# css ui themeroller applied to full calendar change my main css

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I met some trouble while using jquery css theme roller with the js full calendar. In fact I've tried to apply a theme so I used the theme roller to make it pass with my main theme of my website.

The only trouble I met is that it totally change the main property I've defined.

For example I do not have the hover on events, or it does not respect the nowrap proerty I've applied.

I really do not know what to do. Because Changing the css, will also change other elements on my website.

Below is how it looks like [image]

I would like to have previous, next on the same line.

And hover coler event.

any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Setting this up in a JSFiddle, as well as providing your CSS would go a long way in getting an answer that would help you.

Comment: I use the themeroller css. but you can access to my website if I provide you user & password ?